# TextBox and Thread

Tags: c#, textbox

Why doesn't this work?

The program stops on: `this.textBox1.Text = "(New text)";`

```
 Thread demoThread;
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     this.demoThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.ThreadProcUnsafe));
     this.demoThread.Start();

     textBox1.Text = "Written by the main thread.";
 }

 private void ThreadProcUnsafe()
 {
     while (true)
     {
         Thread.Sleep(2000);
         this.textBox1.Text = "(New text)";           
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `Control.Invoke` when performing these operations from a background thread:

```
private void ThreadProcUnsafe()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        textBox1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            textBox1.Text = "(New Text)";
        }));
    }
}
```

If you are writing generic code that *may* be run from a background thread, you can also check the `Control.InvokeRequired` property, as in:

```
if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
{
    textBox1.Invoke(...);
}
else
{
    // Original code here
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In windows, a control may only be updated by the thread that created it. You need to use `Control.Invoke` to marshall a method call to the UI thread to update the text.

There is an example of this on the MSDN  [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) page.

Comment: You can use the this.InvokeRequired method to see if the thread that is executing is the UI thread.  If .InvokeRequired is false you can safely update the .Text property of the control.

Comment: Absolutely - but in his example it is required.

Answer (score 2):

Cross-thread access to Windows controls is not allowed. You need another, less direct mechanism such as event or message passing.

[Here's an article](http://kristofverbiest.blogspot.com/2007/02/avoid-invoke-prefer-begininvoke.html) on the Control.Invoke issue and why BeginInvoke is a better choice due to less chance of deadlock.

Answer (score 2):

Although I recommend using `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` (after calling `InvokeRequired` of course), you can prevent the cross-thread exception altogether by calling this from your Form or UserControl:

```
CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
```

(`CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` is a static property of `Control`)

If you choose to do this, you *may* get some weird-looking results in your UI.